# Restricting d3.js zoom to container

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

consider the following structure:

```
<svg width="720" height="560" style="outline: red;">
   <g width="640" height="480" transform="translate(40,40)" style="outline: blue;">
     <g class="container" width="640" height="480">
       <!-- more stuff here... !-->
     </g>
   </g>
</svg>
```

so now we have two squares via the outlines, the outer one red, and the inner one blue.

I added zoom behavior on the `.container` but when it zooms out it goes beyond the bounds of the g element, and cover the whole `svg` area.

I am trying to limit the zoom so that it is restricted to the 640x480 area, and whatever falls outside that region to be hidden, so that the white margins between the red box and the blue box remain unchanged on zoom.

Currently the blue box's size is modified and consumes the margins when it expands.

How can I achieve that?  see fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/1cg16x02/2/

Comment: Maybe you're asking the wrong question? It seems to be working as expected.

Comment: I'm trying to keep the white margins between the red box and the blue box unmodified, and to have the zoom only inside the blue box, without modifying the size of the blue box itself.  currently the blue box's size is modified and consumes the margins when it expands, which might be the expected behavior, but not my desired result.

Comment: When you think about it, the `g` element that you are trying to keep the same size actually has no size... its just a grouping element so it's dimensions are determined by the objects in the group.  If you check out the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#Groups) it doesn't have `height` and `width` elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I would rather make the first `g` element another `svg` element and add `x` and `y` attributes to it, like this:

```
var g1 = svg.append("svg")
    .attr("x", margin.left)
    .attr("y", margin.top)
```

And in the css, select the outer container by its class to change its outline:

```
.outline .svg-frame {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

To get make an outline for the inner svg, I would add a rectangle to `g1` after the container has been added:

```
g1.append("rect")
    .attr("width", innerWidth)
    .attr("height", innerHeight)
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke", "blue");
```